# Seamless integration of payu

Tags: magento-1.8, payment-methods

I want to integrate payu seamless integration in magento 1.8 for India. But not able to find any solution or any extension. Please give some solution.

Comment: Why this question is down-voted?

Answer (score 4):

I decided to Google "payu magento" and someone has already developed a extension for this:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/payu-payment-gateway.html

There also seems to be a open source extension here:

https://github.com/PayU/plugin_magento

**I am not recommending either one, however you should take a look at them.**

If you feel like developing your own, these guides can help you:

http://developers.payu.com/en/restapi.html
*This is assuming you know how to create a extension in Magento.*

Comment: But I am talking about seamless integration.

Comment: Why wouldn't you consider these seamless integrations?

Comment: I am looking for an extension

Comment: I do not think you know what an extension is. The first two links are clearly a extension for Magento. This is as clear as day. The third link is if you want to build  your own extension.

Comment: I don't think you are getting the point right. I a talking about seamless integration means payment on our site not on payu site. And the extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/payu-payment-gateway.html is redirecting to payu website for payment.

Comment: (facepalm) Then according to PayU (source: http://help.payu.co.za/display/developers/Integration%3A+Enterprise+API) you will need to purchase the Enterprise API. According to their Wiki, they do not have a Magento Extension for the Enterprise API however have posted code examples for it (source: http://help.payu.co.za/display/developers/Get+involved+on+Github). I suggest you build your own.